# Want help to create a list in as3/flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to create a scrollable list in flash/as3 and the important thing is.... if the user wants to move some list item up or down... he can do that by dragging the item... so when he press and hold on an item... the item will become drag-able and as the user moves it up or down the list, the other items should slide to the empty space. Its the same behavior seen in smartphones....

I'll figure out the creation, data filling, scrolling, and other mouse interaction events.... i just want help with this one behavior....of changing the order of items by dragging them. If only someone can just provide the basic algorithm or any idea how this can be achieved.. it will be enough.

​Thanks in advance

**EDITS :**

First of all... i apologize for not posting any details about the question... (this is my first post to this site) and hence i am adding all the research and what i have done so far.

- the list is part of a big project hence i cannot share the whole code.

WHAT I HAVE ALREADY DONE :

- i have created a mask, a container, a scroll bar to scroll the container, items to add into the list, methods to add items, remove items and arrange them according to the order.
- hence it is a scrallable and working list.
- the whole thing is in as3 and flash only.
- i don't know flex and i don't want to use it either.

WHAT I WANT NEXT :

- i want to change the order of these items by (mouse_down on an item -> drag it up/down -> mouse_up at the position) sequence.

If anyone wants more details i can share it.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: what research have you done. what have you tried already?  post some code

Comment: @DigitalBiscuits Sir i have made some edits... plz check them.. and tell me if u need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple List component to an application

In this example, the List consists of labels that identify car models and data fields that contain prices.

Create a new Flash (ActionScript 3.0) document.

Drag a List component from the Components panel to the Stage.

In the Property inspector, do the following:

Enter the instance name  aList .

Assign a value of  200  to the W (width).

Use the Text tool to create a text field below  aList  and give it an instance name of  aTf  .

Open the Actions panel, select Frame 1 in the main Timeline, and enter the following ActionScript code:

```
import fl.controls.List; 
import flash.text.TextField; 

aTf.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC; 
aTf.border = false; 

// Create these items in the Property inspector when data and label 
// parameters are available. 
aList.addItem({label:"1956 Chevy (Cherry Red)", data:35000}); 
aList.addItem({label:"1966 Mustang (Classic)", data:27000}); 
aList.addItem({label:"1976 Volvo (Xcllnt Cond)", data:17000}); 
aList.allowMultipleSelection = true; 

aList.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, showData); 

function showData(event:Event) { 
    aTf.text = "This car is priced at: $" + event.target.selectedItem.data; 
}
```

This code uses the  addItem()  method to populate  aList  with three items, assigning each one a  label  value, which appears in the list, and a  data  value. When you select an item in the List, the event listener calls the  showData()  function, which displays the  data  value for the selected item.

Select Control > Test Movie to compile and run this application.

source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa6.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have got the answer from some other forum.

Here is the link to the example (behavior) that i want to add to my list :

http://www.learningactionscript3.com/2008/05/13/the-power-of-relative-positioning/

(at the bottom 'Advanced Align Example').